# PHP MySQL group by unix Timestamp for reports

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table tbl_news, and I wanted to create several reports such us today, this week, this month.

I have stored time in unix timestamp at "news_adate". For this week report I am using the following query.

```
$first = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("monday this week"));
$last = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("sunday this week"));

$first = $first ." 00:00:01";
$last = $last ." 23:59:59";

$query = "SELECT count(nid), news_adate FROM tbl_news WHERE (news_adate between '".$first."' AND '".$last."') AND tbl_news.news_status=1 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate))" ;
```

I got the following output.

```
25-Oct 2015     1

27-Oct 2015     45
```

But actually it should be

```
25-Oct 2015     1

26-Oct 2015     35

27-Oct 2015     10
```

Don't know where is the error?

Comment: There might be a problem in group by just put `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate))` in select and check that what it prints. I guess it return only two date

Comment: yes, but it should return 3 dates

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark but you're missing the midnight hour by saying between 00:00:01 and 23:59:59 right? What prompted you to use the Unix timestamp rather than the MySQL now() function to store your date time values?I find querying against the MySQL date format substantially easier and more manipulatable with MySQL functions like trunc(). Typically I store both but when querying against dates I prefer the MySQL date time column as opposed to an integer representing a time.
So my first suggestion is to check this output:

```
 $first = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("monday this week"));
$last = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("sunday this week"));

$first = $first ." 00:00:01";
$last = $last ." 23:59:59";

$query = "SELECT count(nid), news_adate FROM tbl_news WHERE (news_adate between '".$first."' AND '".$last."') AND tbl_news.news_status=1 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate))" ;

Echo $query;
```

Anytime you're constructing a query you should check the value of the string to ensure it truly is what you want it to query.

You can also use a SQL tool like toad to help you construct valid queries and check their output before replacing hard values with variables.

Comment: Its a old database, just trying to create a report page.

Comment: Then start by removing the where dates between and see the output... Also change that start time to 00:00:00 instead of 00:00:01

Comment: Done but the still getting 2 dates instead of 3. Any other query to get it?

Comment: Query is : SELECT count(nid), news_adate FROM tbl_news WHERE (news_adate between '1445797800' AND '1446402599') AND tbl_news.news_status=1 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate)) and the output is count(nid) news_adate 1
1445798040
45
1445911020

Comment: if you need to use between, add one day to the edge of time.
or using " Where news_adate <= '".$first."' AND news_adate >= '".$last."' "

Comment: same output, the problem is with the 'group by'

Comment: @Binu j the timestamp values are:
1445797800: GMT: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 18:30:00 GMT and
1446402599  GMT: Sun, 01 Nov 2015 18:29:59 GMT

Between is inclusive - so do not add anything you don't want to the between statement. between 1 and 10 would yield results >=1 and <= 10.

Comment: @binuj If you change the group by to trunc(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate))) what does that output look like?

Comment: getting error "FUNCTION mydatabase.trunc does not exist"

Comment: Yeah sorry trunc is oracle syntax Google the equivalent MySQL function

Comment: You may already be truncating the date properly with your function... try what sandeepsure suggested and put the DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_news.news_adate)) in the select portion of the query and see what the output looks like........... otherwise here is a link to learn about trunc for mysql: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/175745